# Determinant as a Hamiltonian

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, sg.symplectic-geometry, determinants, classical-mechanics

Are there two  symplectic  structures $\omega_1, \omega_2$ on $M_{2n}(\mathbb{R})$  such that the  function $Det:M_{2n}(\mathbb{R})\to \mathbb{R}$ is completely integrable  with respect to $\omega_{1}$ but is not  completely integrable  with respect to  $\omega_2$ ?

Note  that we do  not limit the  symplectic  structures  to structures  with  constant  coefficients.

I  had already asked  a weaker version of this  question in the  following  link but I confess that I  did  not  understand the  details (How  does the  action of orthonormal group  guarantees the  integrability?)

http://mathforum.org/kb/thread.jspa?forumID=253&threadID=1653483&messageID=5990478#5990478

**Correction of the above  Mathforum link:**  For $n=1$, the appropriate first integral showing complete integrability of  $Det =xw-yz$ is $xz+yw$. It  works on $M_{2}(\mathbb{R})\setminus \{0\}$. At the origin(the  zero matrix) we  loose the  independence of  differentials  of two  first integrals.

Comment: What is the definition of "complete integrability" you are using ?

Comment: @KonstantinosKanakoglou  Sorry for my delay. I mean the standard definition: existence of n independent first integral $f_1,f_2,\ldots, f_n$ with $\omega(X_{f_i},X_{f_j})=0$.

Comment: this is a quite interesting question. I do not know the answer in general, but i think that -since you are asking a scenario involving differerent symplectic structures on the same underlying manifold- that the question transcends hamiltonian mechanics. So, i was thinking of suggesting that maybe the question should be retagged: "Classical Mechanics" seems more suitable -imo- than "hamiltonian mechanics" and maybe "differential geometry" would be better than "hamiltonian vector fields".

Comment: Don't misunderstand me, i am just trying to think of ways to increase the visibility of the question.

Comment: @KonstantinosKanakoglou  Thank  you  very  much  for  your interesting suggestion. I  revise  the tags.

Comment: @KonstantinosKanakoglou  I just find  the  following  interesting MO  answer indivcating  a  given hamiltonian can generate two  dynamically different flows  associated to different  symplectic  structures     https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35900/when-is-a-symplectic-manifold-equivalent-to-a-cotangent-bundle/36068#36068